# Problems using the XSP Starter Kit

Tags: xpages

I followed the instructions to install the XSP Starter kit from openntf. Everything mentioned in the video I was able to do but I am not able to activate it.

When I activate the plugin in my application and try to open it I get an Error 500. Anybody any idea?

The server console tells me:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2a0nlmjj5prnxs/Error%20OSGI.jpg?dl=0

The log file contains:

```
<extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
    <values>java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:461)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.initModule(NSFComponentModule.java:498)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.createNSFModule(NSFService.java:752)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.loadModule(NSFService.java:735)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:588)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.j</values>
    <values>ava:272)&#xA;Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:89)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.BootStrap.init(BootStrap.java:82)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.ConfigureCoreListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureCoreListener.java:39)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:453)&#xA;&#x9;... 8 more&#xA;Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:417)&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.config.CLBootStrap.initContext(CLBootStrap.java:81)&#xA;&#x9;... 11 more&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstan</values>
    <values>ceImpl(Native Method)&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1549)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:926)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:965)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:489)&#xA;&#x9;at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:410)&#xA;&#x9;... 12 more&#xA;</values>
</extendedDataElements>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a component that was available in the starter kit for org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer. It's hitting an error trying to create that component. It's not a component designed to be used in a particular way, it's really there to show what needs to be created for a component - org.openntf.xsp.starter.AbstractHtmlTag is the component, html.xsp-config in META-INF defines the properties available to Domino Designer, html-faces-config adds the component to the server and defines which Java class to use for the component and which one for the renderer (to display the HTML). org.openntf.xsp.starter.renderkit.AbstractHtmlTagRenderer handles printing content to the browser.

I've not used the starter kit as is, but I did use it as a basis for my session at ICON UK http://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1/from-xpages-hero-to-osgi-guru-taking-the-scary-out-of-building-extension-libraries-icon-uk-2014

Comment: I am now using the bootstrap4xpages library as a starting point into osgi plugins. Its easier to understand and to manipulate. I am still struggeling with SSJS but beside that everything works fine

Comment: Yes, adding new SSJS functions are convoluted. There are constants that map to integers at the top. The constructor calls addFunction() to map that constant to an @Function name - I can't remember what the third parameter is, it's either the SSJS return value type or a parameter type. NotesFunction.call() then has a switch statement to map to the relevant Java function based on the constant's integer. You then also need the Java method to do your code. Nathan T. Freeman made the whole code more automatic for OpenNTF Domino API, automatically adding all methods for chosen classes.

Comment: Sorry your level is way to high for me. I didnt understand a word. Is there a good documentation/book you can recommend? I forgot to ask: Can i also put views into the plugin?